# How to use nullable in foregin in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, migration

I create migration in laravel 5.6.

I need add user information if the user was logged in my website else add `0` in column.

My code is:

```
$table->integer('user_id')->default(0);
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

But aftre run `migrate` show this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

I need add default `0` or `null` in column or add `user_id` in column if the user was logged in my website.

How to issue this problem?

Comment: The answers given here should work. Although there is an alternative solution. You can set default value for `user_id` in store/update method in controller. Just a thought. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make it `unsigned` and `nullable`. Also, it's a good idea to separate creating a column and adding foreign key logic to avoid similar errors:

```
Schema::create('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable();
});

Schema::table('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Data type will be diffrent for both `user_id` and `id` in users table.

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

Primary keys created using in `increments()` will be unsigned integer

Answer (score 0):

Use this short method

```
  $table->foreignId('user_id')
                ->constrained()
                ->onUpdate('cascade')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Laravel is smart enough to know that you are referencing to the users table

Answer (score -1):

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

try this