# Laravel migration does not create cross schema foreign key in PostgreSQL database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations

I have 2 schemas on the same PostgreSQL database but on separate schemas (logs and auth).
When I run the following migrations the foreign key is not created in the database (it doesn't throw any errors while running migration).

```
 Schema::connection('auth')->create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            ...
        });
```

```
 Schema::connection('logs')->create($table, function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
                ...
                $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('auth.users');
               // I've tried also (without any effect)
              //  $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on(new Expression('auth.users'));
               // Those 2 throw errors
              //  $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on(new Expression('users'));
              //  $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

Comment: try these solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/49124896/2384882 , by separating create table with adding foreign key(s) to table

Comment: @Win Unfortuantely it didn't help. When I run the very same migration on the remote PostgreSQL db server it works fine. It looks like it doesn't create the FK only on my localhost PostgreSQL (running on Windows).

Comment: probably when on windows best to run either inside docker , use virtual or just plain simple dualboot